# Save value of a drop-down list and reassign it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop-down list with options 1 through 10. When the selected item is 10, the drop-down is replaced by a textbox with the number 10 inside the textbox.

In the event that a user selects 10 from the drop-down, and then clears the 10 and leaves the box empty, I want to go back and reassign the value that was selected *before the drop-down was turned into a textbox*.

For example: if the user had selected a 3 in the drop-down, and then selected 10, I want to leave the 10 in the textbox. If the value is cleared, and the textbox is turned into the drop-down again, I want to reassign to 3.

Here is the drop-down markup:

```
<select id='qty'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
<option value='6'>6</option>
<option value='7'>7</option>
<option value='8'>8</option>    
<option value='9'>9</option>
<option value='10'>10+</option>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#qty').live('change', function () {
if ((this.value) == 10) {
    $(this).replaceWith($('<input/>', {
        'type': 'text',
            'value': +(this.value)
        }));
    }
});
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qje6uywg/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var lastValue;

    $('#qty').live('change', function () {
       if ((this.value) == 10) {
           $(this).replaceWith($('<input/>', {
               'type': 'text',
               'value': +(this.value)
            }));
       }
       else{
          lastValue = this.value;
       }
    });
```

And then use lastValue to reset the value of the selectbox when you have to show it.

EDIT : modified the jsfiddle, you jsut need to create the list again
http://jsfiddle.net/qje6uywg/5/

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add the id on the input when you replace it so it will change also when you change the value of the text input. But is very similar to dupa response.

```
$('#qty').live('change', function () {
   if ((this.value) == 10) {
     $(this).replaceWith($('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
        'value': + (this.value),
        'id': 'qty'
     }));
   } else if ( this.value === '' && $(this).prop('type') === 'text' ) {
     console.log('Do whatever you want when value is empty');
  }
});
```

Comment: I thought that there is a .blur() event that needs to be executed when the textbox loses focus.

Comment: Yes, both change and blur will change when the textbox loses focus, if you want to use blur you just have to create a new live event for your textbox.

Comment: In the part 'Do whatever you want...', I added a: $('#qty').show to show the drop-down list but it does not work. Is not this correct?

Comment: No, when you use `$(this).replaceWith()` function you're replacing the select input with the text input. So the select input no longer exists, you would have to replace the text input with the select input again.